# Laravel Shopping Cart Update quantity inc-desc Package(darryldecode)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to increase or decrease the quantity on the cart page, but when I try to increase or decrease the quantity it adds to the amount it is taking.

Sample;

Quantity jumps from 1 to 3. So **$cartItems += 1**

In short it doesn't work on increasing or decreasing how can I increase and decrease one by one?

Following my code :
`app.js`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$('.qty-inc, .qty-desc').on('click',function () {
    var id =$(this).attr('data-id');
    var qty =$(this).attr('data-qty');
    $.ajax({
        type:'PATCH',
        url:'basket/update/'+id,
        data:{qty:qty},
        success:function () {
        window.location.href='/basket';
        }
    });
});
```

`Route`

```
Route::patch('basket/update/{userID}','App\Http\Controllers\BasketController@update')->name('basket.update');
```

`Controller`

```
use Cart;
public function update($userID){
  Cart::update($userID,[
   'quantity' => request('qty')
   ]);

   return response()->json(['success' => true]);
}
```

`basket.blade.php`

```
@foreach(Cart::getContent() as $cartItems)

<a href="#" class="qty-desc" data-id="{{ $cartItems->id }}" data-qty="{{$cartItems->quantity-1}}">-</a>

<span style="padding: 10px 20px">{{ $cartItems->quantity }}</span>

<a href="#" class="qty-inc" data-id="{{ $cartItems->id }}" data-qty="{{$cartItems->quantity+1}}">+</a>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, maybe I'm sharing it in case someone needs it.
`Controller`

```
Cart::update($userID,[
    'quantity' => array(
     'relative' => false,
     'value' => request('qty')
     ),
 ]);
```